# Pulling certain information from second table but without a "Where" constraint

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have been able to learn  and figure out how to pull information doing LEFT JOIN.   Now, I need to pull all information from a table and then use the user_id from that table to pull the users full_name from the accounts table.  Below is the code I am using:

Code:

```
  $query="SELECT * FROM messages_questions ORDER BY id ASC";
  $result=mysql_query($query);

  $num=mysql_numrows($result);

  mysql_close();

  echo "";

   $i=0;
   while ($i < $num) {

   $messages=mysql_result($result,$i,"messages_title");
   $asker = mysql_result($result,$i,"user_id");
   $comp = mysql_result($result,$i,"comp_id");


   echo "<div id=container><br><div id=message>$messages<br>Asked by $asker</div>
   </div>";

    echo "";

        $i++;
     }
```

How can I tweak it to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information about your tables would be useful, however you need something like this:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM messages_questions AS mq
JOIN accounts AS a
ON mq.user_id = a.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like

```
SELECT mq.messages_title,mq.user_id,mq.comp_id, a.full_name
FROM messages_questions mq 
LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.user_id = mq.user_id
ORDER BY mq.id ASC
```